# No definition for class and cannot find the argument c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have been working on a clone of brick breaker to get better in C# but keep getting this error
"Error  1   'WPFGame1.Gammer' does not contain a definition for 'Window_KeyDown' and no extension method 'Window_KeyDown' accepting a first argument of type 'WPFGame1.Gammer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
It's a WPF and I have the it declared in the class
There is a lot of useless CS that you don't need, but I just wanted everything to be there in case you needed something else.
Here's the relevent XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WPFGame1.Gammer" Name="myWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    ResizeMode="CanMinimize"
    Title="Brick Breaker" Height="650" Width="700" 
    KeyDown="Window_KeyDown" <!--error occurs here-->
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
    >
```

And the CS

```
public class Gammer : Window, IComponentConnector{
   private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Gammer.movingTimer.IsEnabled && e.Key == Key.Space)
            {
                Gammer.movingTimer.Stop();
                Pause p = new Pause(this);
                p.ShowDialog();
            }
            Key key = e.Key;
            if (key <= Key.F)
            {
                switch (key)
                {
                    case Key.Left:
                        {
                            double leftRed = Canvas.GetLeft(this.rectangleRed);
                            if (leftRed > 0.0)
                            {
                                Canvas.SetLeft(this.rectangleRed, leftRed - 20);
                                return;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    case Key.Up:
                        break;
                    case Key.Right:
                        double rightRed = Canvas.GetLeft(this.rectangleRed);
                        if (rightRed < 550.0)
                        {
                            Canvas.SetLeft(this.rectangleRed, rightRed + 20);
                            return;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        if (key != Key.F)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                        double rightBlue = Canvas.GetLeft(this.rectangleBlue);
                        if (rightBlue < 550.0)
                        {
                            Canvas.SetLeft(this.rectangleBlue, rightBlue + 20);
                        }
                        break;
                }
                }
            else if(key != Key.F)
            {
                if(key == Key.F1)
                {
                    Help h = new Help();
                    h.Show();
                    return;
                }
                if(key != Key.F5)
                {
                    return;
                }
                Touch.FrameReported += new TouchFrameEventHandler(this.Touch_FrameReportedRed);
                Gammer.movingTimer.Start();
                this.currentGameState = 1;
                this.setInitialState();
                this.clearCanvas();
                this.brickGenerator(this.currentGameState);
                return;
            }else
            {
                double leftBlue = Canvas.GetLeft(this.rectangleBlue);
                if(leftBlue > 0.0)
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(this.rectangleBlue, leftBlue - 20.0);
                    return;

                }
            }
            }}
```

Comment: Everything looks perfect to me. Sometimes visual studio is a bit buggy. Try cleaning the solution and restarting visual studio.

Comment: Still the same error, could it have something with me switching between editing it on 2010 and 2015?

Comment: @CathalMF assuming a bug for a clear compiler error is ... presumptuous. The code does *not* look perferct - designer generated classes are partial. This class is not. Cleaning won't fix coding errors

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ive had alot of those errors in visual studio 2010 when working on WPF and restarting fixed it. I hadnt noticed the missing  partial class.

Comment: @CathalMF 2010 was ... 6 years ago. Restarting may have fixed anything *except* a compiler or runtime error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Gammer : Window, IComponentConnector{
```

Try switching that to this

```
public partial class Gammer : Window, IComponentConnector{
```

Comment: Ya good point. I have no idea how the OP even has a non partial class here. In wpf there should be the autogenered class in the background.

Comment: Still get the error when I run the program, I tried changing the name of the method with no luck as well, would it help if I posted the rest of the code?

Comment: Is this all of the program?
usually every WPF application has a constructor with an initialize component

Also is the namespace WPFGame1?

Comment: @Cottenballzz don't assume that VS has a problem. Removing the `partial` keyword is a *serious* issue. *All* code-behind classes are partial. How was this class generated? Did you create it yourself? Did you delete the existing class with that name? Are the class names correct? In which *namespace* was this class created? Your window is created in the `WPFGame1` namespace. A class with the same name in another namespace is still a different class

Comment: No, this is just a small portion of the code as if I posted it all it wouldn't make sense to have you comb through a ton of lines of code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The namespace names are different, I can't believe I missed that, thank you!

Comment: @Cottenballzz that ton of code is where the coding error is. Remove *all* of the code and leave only the relevant parts. Also include the namespace declaration. Although I'm certain you created a class in a different namespace, otherwise the compiler would complain that you had already declared the class

Comment: @Cottenballzz No worries. Is the constructor there though? usually its something like

public Window() {
intializecomponent();
}

Comment: @bcpermafrost this shouldn't matter as the generated class will already have a constructor. Of course, if this class has a parameterless constructor, there will be another compilation error

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Fair point. Its more of a sanity check though to make sure that things are setup properly